# vue flatpickr not showing defaultDate when there is just one enabled day

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, flatpickr

I am using 'vue-flatpickr-component' in my app and I have a problem with the defaultDate when I enable specific dates in its config. I have a function that fetches some values from the backend and than populates the config object.

````
  let config = (field)=>{
    altFormat: "d.m.y",
    altInput: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    allowInput: true,
    weekNumbers: false,
    disableMobile: true,
    minDate: "",
    maxDate: "",
    onClose: updateDatePicker,
    defaultDate: "",
  }if (
      searchStore.searchFieldValues[field.name] === undefined
    ) {
      searchStore.searchFieldValues[field.name] =
        utils.formatDate(tariffManagerConfig.defaultValue);
    }
    config.altFormat = tariffManagerConfig.altFormat;
   ------------------
    config.disableMobile = tariffManagerConfig.disableMobile;
    config.defaultDate = utils.formatDate(tariffManagerConfig.defaultValue);
    if (tariffManagerConfig.disable) {
      Object.assign(config, { disable: [] as any[] });
      config.disable.push(tariffManagerConfig.disable);
    }
    if (tariffManagerConfig.enable) {
      Object.assign(config, { enable: [] as any[] });
      config.enable.push(tariffManagerConfig.enable);
    }
  }
  return config;
};```

>The enable value is ["2023-08-01"], the defaultValue is "2023-08-01" and the dateFormat is 'Y-m-d'. If enable is not in the config object or if enable has a range of dates as value, the calendar starts on the defaultDate, otherwise it shows the current month. Any idea of what could cause the problem? I have tried using the Date() constructor and than initialising the hour to midnight, but it didn't work.
````